# Different way of saying "throw rubbish" in Cantonese?

Tags: characters, cantonese, word-requests

Looking at the dictionary, I see that "throw rubbish" in Cantonese is "掉垃圾". However, in the past, I remember hearing something different for "throw rubbish": "wang垃圾".

I need some help:

- What is the character used to represent "wang" in "wang垃圾"?
- In what region is "wang垃圾" used? It certainly does not appear to be Guangzhou or Hong Kong Cantonese.

Comment: Pretty sure it is not Malaysian Cantonese either.

Comment: @ChanMT What's "throw rubbish" in Malaysian Cantonese?

Comment: Same as what you mentioned: 掉垃圾，deu6 laap6 saap3.

Answer (score 2):

In Cantonese, we seldom say 扔(weng1)垃圾 as 扔 is more commonly used in wriiten Chinese. We either say 掉(deu6) 垃圾 or 抌(dam2)垃圾

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *reng*

> 扔

The phrase:

> 扔垃圾

Can mean either to discard of garbage or litter.

Comment: "扔" isn't pronounced as "wang", so I don't think this is it.

Comment: @Flux *Reng* could easily be misheard as *wang*. There aren't many other combinations of `x + 垃圾`.

Comment: reng1 (pinyin) is the Mandarin pronunciation of "扔", but this question is about Cangtonese. "扔" is pronounced wing1 (Jyutping) in Cantonese. However, "扔" is rarely used in Cantonese. "Throw" can be said in Cantonese as "掟" (deng3) or (in the case of trash) "抌" (dam2), but neither of those sound close to "wang".

Comment: @user102008 Maybe it’s 广普?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have heard "Dell" 垃圾 in spoken Cantonese
but I don't know how to write the word "dell"